# Monitor microphone sound level

Tags: windows, monitoring, microphone

I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows that can display a small window that monitor microphone sound level in real-time.

I know that Audacity and Camtasia monitor microphone sound level, but only when they are recording:

[image]

[image]

I'm also aware of the fact that the sound setting window in Microsoft Windows does display the real-time microphone sound level, but I would prefer a smaller window:

[image]

Any license and price is fine.

Comment: Franck, I don't know of one for Windows (hopefully someone else does), but I can recommend a couple for Android, if that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

> Power Mixer is an advanced Windows audio mixer, a complete replacement
> for the standard Windows volume control. This application lets you
> easily change the sound volume just by rotating the mouse wheel or by
> using keyboard hot keys. It includes an audio mixer with advanced
> volume controls support, a scheduler, an on-screen display, command
> line support, the ability to store and recall different unlimited
> presets via one mouse click or system-wide hot keys. By using presets
> you can change all parameters of sound simultaneously! It is designed
> to be especially useful for those who play games, work professionally
> with sound, or are everyday users.

In your case you can resize and move the mixer window.

**EDIT:** I noticed that you can't make it too much small.

[Power Mixer web page](https://www.actualsolution.com/power-mixer/)

[Power Mixer trial download page](https://www.actualsolution.com/download/)

[image: Power Mixer screenshot]

[image: Power Mixer screenshot]
<sub>(source: [blogspot.com](https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-GxMMX0vgN20/W5qg7z3N2uI/AAAAAAAAAH4/72ZJGx0X_aU5ie1vGbO9I6d2EiMzOAoXQCLcBGAs/s1600/02.png))</sub>